# Ruby on Rails: Make Float Value to be limited to 5 decimal places

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a variable in my code which accepts float type values. I want my field to be able to accept values up to 5 decimal places (0.00007). How can i do it in rails

```
<%= user_fields.text_field :conversion_rate, required: true, maxlength: 8 %>
```

i read somewhere about using `:step` but it is not working for my code.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= f.number_field :conversion_rate, :step => 0.00001 %>
```

Take note that I'm using a `number_field` helper, and not a `text_field_helper`, which is probably why you couldn't get the `:step` option to work.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser you can restrict by using regular expressions in javascript like on change of the field you can count the characters and update the field accordingly.

In case you wanted to store only 5 decimals in database there are options like precision and scale.

precision - total digits before the dot
scale - total digits after the dot.